# React Native Display value of Animation as it changes

Tags: javascript, react-native

New to JS and React Native
How do I display the value of an animation as it changes.
I have a working rotation animation and have tried adding an event listener which updates variable as below but get nothing in the Text view after the colon.

```
  var spin = this.state.spinValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-60, 60],
    outputRange: ['-125deg', '125deg'],
  });

  // AppState.addEventListener('change', this.state.spinValue._value);
  this.state.spinValue.addListener(({value}) => this._value = value);


  <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize:20}}>Rotation value : {this._value}
```

Comment: What is `spinValue`? If it's not too big, could you please add the complete code?

Comment: You can use `this.state.spinValue._value` if you don't want to update the state that much for performance reasons. Check  https://stackoverflow.com/a/60850210/3863740

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component won't update until you call `setState` on it, so instead of storing the value in a class instance property `this._value`, you can store it in state (`this.state.value`), and update it with `this.setState({ value: value });`

Just make sure that you don't attach the even listener in your render method, as that will add a new listener every time a new event comes in.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I managed to work out the setState bit but perf was incredibly slow. Thankfully you answered that bit. Moving the addListener to componentDidMount makes it work perfect.