# Display Animated Value in React Native Render Text Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I can not display the Value of Animated on the Render and returns this error.

> Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {value}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Of course, I see the Value in the `console`

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state={
       progress:0
    }

    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0);

    this.animatedValue.addListener((progress) => {
        this.setState({progress})
    });
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.animate()
}

animate() {
    this.animatedValue.setValue(0);
    Animated.timing(
        this.animatedValue,
        {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 15000,
            easing: Easing.linear
        }
    ).start()
}

render() {
    return(
        <View>
            <Text> {this.state.progress} </Text>
        </View>
    );

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function given to `addListener` will be called with an object with a `value` key as argument, so instead of setting `progress` with the entire object, use the `value` instead:

```
this.animatedValue.addListener((progress) => {
  this.setState({ progress: progress.value });
});
```

Comment: This will causes state of component changes, and so Re-rendering!, am I right? if yes, any better idea exists?

Comment: A good way to avoid unnecessary re-renders would be to depend upon a condition before calling `setState`, e.g., `if (Math.round(progress.value) !== this.state.progress)`

Comment: Another way of avoiding too many rerenders is using a throttle

Answer (score 1):

Tholle solution works fine if the animated value doesn't change that much, because it will cause a component re-render(as mentioned by @saeedZhiany in his comment) each time the value changes and that can lead to performance issues.

The better solution for these cases is to use `._value` property of `animatedValue`, something like this:

```
 <Text>
    {Math.round(this.animatedValue._value)}
 </Text>
```

This way you get the real value at anytime without updating the component state. Thus avoiding performance issues.

Comment: Note: If `useNativeDriver: true` this will always return 0.